# Cannot resize Visual Studio 2010 "Add Reference" Window

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2010

So I was trying to add a reference to my project and opened `Add Reference` dialog box. I accidentally double click on the caption of the window which maximized the window. then I tried to restore it  by double clicking again and it didn't work, so I closed the window, hoping re-open will fix it. after re-open window become full screen and I cannot resize it anymore. It is not maximized just full screen. I can move it around and although cursor changes to resize on the borders of window, it does not resize.

I deleted visual studio settings from both folders 
\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\settings
%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio

Deleted registry HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio

And dialog is still same size.

I don't have this problem with Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 8.1 or 7, It only happens in Windows 10.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this issue.
Obviously it wasn't an issue with Visual Studio 2010 but from Windows 10.

For a reason that is not clear for me, Explorer stores the size and location of window that is not related to it in anyway. I tracked the open and close of the window and it was writing windows size in this locatin.

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32

unfortunately there is no easy way to say which ID belongs to mentioned Add Reference window so I deleted all and window returned to normal size.

However if you try to grab the window and change its size, you can increase it but you cannot reduce it.